# How to properly schedule while function to be interrupted and another function called

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, scheduled-tasks, thread-synchronization

I have a script that runs pretty much 24/7. I would like it to be properly interrupted several times a day.

```
from time import sleep

def function_one():
    while True:
        print("I'm working 24/7 and doing some important stuff here!")
        print("Very important!")
        sleep(5)

def function_two():
    print("I just need to do my job once, however, function_one should be stopped while i'm working!")
```

I want `function_one` to be interrupted (in between loops) every 3 hours then `function_two` to be called once and right after that `function_one` should continue working.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: It really depeneds on how complicated is your `function_one` and `function_two` . Do you need to use two separate processes or threads for those functions? If so consider using thread/processes locking mechanism.

Comment: when exactly is `function_two` called?

Comment: function_two is should be called every 3 hours. I.e function_one runs for 3 hours, it stops/loop breaks, function two is called, after function two finishes the job, function_one is called and it  runs again for another 3 hours.

Comment: Have you looked at the [sched module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)? It provides actual scheduling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put the call to function 2 within function 1 itself. That way it'll wait until function 2 has run to resume function 1. Something like this:

```
from __future__ import generators
from time import sleep
import time

def function_one():
    while True:
        print("I'm working 24/7 and doing some important stuff here!")
        print("Very important!")
        #First bit checks whether the hour is divisible by 3 (every 3 hours)
                                                #This bit checks that the minute and seconds combined are the first 5 seconds of the hour
        if int(time.strftime("%H"))%3 == 0 and int(time.strftime("%M%S")) < 6:
            #Calls function 2 and won't resume until function 2 is finished
            function_two()
            print("That was the 2 second wait from function 2")
        sleep(5)

def function_two():
    print("I just need to do my job once, however, function_one should be stopped while i'm working!")
    sleep(2)

function_one()
```

Hopefully this works for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep, time

def function_one():
    print("I'm working 24/7 and doing some important stuff here!")
    print("Very important!")

def function_two():
    print("I just need to do my job once, however, function_one should be stopped while i'm working!")    

def function_three():
    last_call = time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - last_call > 3 hours:
            last_call = time()
            function_two()  # function_one is not running during the execution of function_two
        function_one()
        sleep(5)
```

Something like this

Comment: This code does not produce the results needed. It will constantly print "I'm working 24/7 and doing some important stuff here!" and "Very important!" and ignores `sleep(5)`

Comment: So what is the code you work with? Keep in mind that you should replace `3 hours` with 3 hours in milliseconds (I guess). I don't see how sleep(5) would be ignored if you call function_three.

Comment: I did replace 3 hours and also replaced time.time() with time() in function_three. I'm not sure why but it did ignore sleep(5)